# Fill excel cell values based on logic

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have filled date and days values in excel (Year 2020). now, I have to fill other 2 column values based on some logic . I can do it manually but it is time consuming. I need to know formula, function to achieve this. below is logic -

1. column- c3,c4 value starts from value 1. it is default.
2. column c3 value depends on c4 value.
3. c3 value remains same for current week till next Monday comes. for every Monday arrival, it is incremented by 1 and remain same for that week.
4. column c3 value remain same till c4 value reaches till 10. it means. c3-1, c4-10
5. After (1,10), next c3 value - starts from 2 and c4 value - 1 and sequence goes until (2,10) and then again till (3,10) and then (4,10).

here is sample excel data for your reference -

[image: sample excel data]

Comment: Point number 3: "c3 value remains same for current week till next Monday comes". Do you mean C4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In E2 put `1`

In E3 put:

```
=IF(WEEKDAY(B3,2)=1,IF(E2=10,1,E2+1),E2)
```

In D2 put `1`

In D3 put:

```
=IF(AND(WEEKDAY(B3,2)=1,E2=10),D2+1,D2)
```

and copy both formula to the bottom of the dataset.

[image]